# Spring Security doesn't always perform logout

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

Here is my Spring Security configuration:

*web.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>tutorial.root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.andrew.springsecuregwt.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/springsecuregwt/greet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Springsecuregwt.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

*applicationContext-security.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <debug />

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/loggedout.jsp" security="none"/>

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="hasRole('supervisor')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login />
        <logout logout-success-url="/loggedout.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <remember-me />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
            <user-service>
                <user name="rod" password="4efe081594ce25ee4efd9f7067f7f678a347bccf2de201f3adf2a3eb544850b465b4e51cdc3fcdde" authorities="supervisor, user, teller" />
                <user name="dianne" password="957ea522524a41cbfb649a3e293d56268f840fd5b661b499b07858bc020d6d223f912e3ab303b00f" authorities="user,teller" />
                <user name="scott" password="fb1f9e48058d30dc21c35ab4cf895e2a80f2f03fac549b51be637196dfb6b2b7276a89c65e38b7a1" authorities="user" />
                <user name="peter" password="e175750688deee19d7179d444bfaf92129f4eea8b4503d83eb8f92a7dd9cda5fbae73638c913e420" authorities="user" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

When I click on the logout link, I'm successfully landing at the logout page, but if I enter

```
localhost:8080/projectname
```

in the new Chrome tab, I can gain access to the app, without any authentication page.

What do I do wrong and how can I fix such security issue?

Comment: Ask in English, please!

Comment: Have you checked your browser isn't just rendering the cached page?

Answer (score 0):

Spring remembeMe functionality creates a cookie with the name 'SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE'. It then uses this to authenticate. If your logout only deletes the webapp container session id the authentication will check for that and then the presence of this cookie. So you need to make sure you remove this cookie on logout.